What is a representation of positive numbers summing to one that can be sampled via HMC?
I have a probability density $f(x): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whose argument vector $x$ satisfies the constraints that all elements are positive and sum to unity. I need to generate samples from $f$. Since $n$ is large, I need to use Hamiltonian Monte Carlo. What is a good $n-1$ dimensional representation of $x$ that I can use as the fundamental variables?
In order to generate such an $x$ from $n-1$ degrees of freedom, one can take $n-1$ numbers in (0,1), sort them, add 0 and 1 at the ends, and take the pairwise differences as $x$. However, this construction is not a bijection. So I assume that it is very inefficient to sample in that representation since there are $(n-1)!$ equivalent modes. There might also be issues with the gradient required for HMC due to the sorting operation.

This is called the n-1 simplex.  It has many useful parameterizations, such as that determined by Helmert matrices as well as those that do not require constraints on the parameters.  I discuss a family of the latter in a thread on the ILR transformation.  It includes working code. Yet another approach is to generate $n$ non-negative values any way you like and normalize them by their sum.  Which is best comes down to the details of your density $f.$ Any hints?

Thank you for your response, I'll need to read these carefully as I'm not familiar. $f$ is actually a normalizing flow and trained on the first $n-1$ elements (it's more complicated, there's a Fourier transform and an optimal transport cost involved -- I don't think these details matter too much, except to say that it's not a functional form I can write down).
